# Change modal dialog to load close to top of the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a jQuery modal dialog that is loading perfectly fine but my issue is that I am using little old version of jQuery(1.12.4) and I cannot upgrade it and I want to center the modal close to the top of the page like I have it in this  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8pt92woL/). I am using the below code to make it work and position: ['center',20], is making it close to the top but again since I am using an old version of the jQuery it is not working for me. Can someone suggest any other alternaate.

```
$('#open').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');

});

$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen:false,
        width:500,
        position: ['center',20],               
        modal: true,
        resizable: true,
        draggable: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,        
        title: "Alerts",       
        buttons: {
            OK: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

In my case loading on the top left corner as shown below
[image: Page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-position) you need to change this line from:

```
position: ['center',20],
```

to:

```
position: { my: "center", at: "top", of: window },
```

Your updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7qdktmsn/1/), the snippet:

```js
$('#open').click(function() {
  $('#dialog').dialog('open');

});



$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#dialog").dialog({
      autoOpen:false,
      width:500,
      position: { my: "center", at: "top", of: window },               
      modal: true,
      resizable: true,
      draggable: true,
      closeOnEscape: true,        
      title: "Alerts",       
      buttons: {
          OK: function () {
              $(this).dialog("close");
          }
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/start/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="dialog">modal dialog</div>
<a href="#" id="open">Open dialog</a>
```